on experiencing nibbana we become sotapanna. so why gautama directly become buddha?
It is said that when you experience nibbana the first time you are sotapanna.
but why buddha did not crossed all these stages. and directly become buddha?

Suttas such as SN 12.10 describe the Bodhisatta's experience that is the same as sotappana (as described in SN 12.28, for example). In SN 12.10, the Bodhisatta was not yet a Buddha but penetrated the reality of Dependent Origination. This is stream-entry, even though the sutta itself never mentions stream-entry.
Similarly, sutta such as MN 14 describe the Bodhisatta as a once-returner & non-returner, as follows:

I myself, before my Awakening, when I was still an unawakened
bodhisatta, saw as it actually was with right discernment that
sensuality is of much stress, much despair & greater drawbacks, but
as long as I had not attained a rapture & pleasure apart from
sensuality, apart from unskillful mental qualities, or something more
peaceful than that, I did not claim that I could not be tempted by
sensuality [ONCE-RETURNER; per Iti 96]. But when I saw as it actually was with right discernment
that sensuality is of much stress, much despair, & greater drawbacks,
and I had attained a rapture & pleasure apart from sensuality, apart
from unskillful mental qualities, or something more peaceful than
that, that was when I claimed that I could not be tempted by
sensuality [NON-RETURNER; per Iti 96].
MN 14

Gautama did not directly become a Buddha.

This is not something that is explicitly stated or explained in the suttas, so we don't actually know if this was in fact the case or not. The progression may simply have happened so quickly that it was barely worth mentioning the stages, or perhaps his unexcelled discernment enabled him to swiftly sever all ten fetters in one fell swoop.
Many descriptions of the path also involve leaving out the preliminary stages of awakening: see, for example, the description of the gradual training in DN2, which is repeated in many discourses.
One interesting thing to notice, though, about the final and crucial part of this stock description - attainment of arahantship - is that it does appear to be divided into two phases:
The first is seeing the noble truths:

He discerns, as it has come to be, that ‘This is stress… This is the origination of stress… This is the cessation of stress… This is the way leading to the cessation of stress…

The second is seeing the same causal pattern regarding the effluents:

These are effluents… This is the origination of effluents… This is the cessation of effluents… This is the way leading to the cessation of effluents.’

As we then see, this cessation of the effluents is what's actually crucial to the attainment of arahantship:

His heart, thus knowing, thus seeing, is released from the effluent of sensuality, the effluent of becoming, the effluent of ignorance. With release, there is the knowledge, ‘Released.’ He discerns that ‘Birth is ended, the holy life fulfilled, the task done. There is nothing further for this world.’

Now it's not certain, but it certainly seems reasonable to consider as a possibility, that this preliminary insight into the four noble truths corresponds to stream-entry. As you note, the attainment is said to involve seeing the deathless, which would correspond to seeing the third noble truth: the cessation of stress and suffering. While some suttas equate seeing the truths with arahantship, AN 3.24 certainly suggests that the truths are seen at stream-entry. So, too does Ratana Sutta

Those who have seen clearly the noble truths
well-taught by the one deeply discerning—
regardless of what [later] might make them heedless—
will come to no eighth state of becoming.3

Further, since neither once-returners nor non-returners have yet seen the ending of the effluents, it would stand to reason that their respective attainments also involve insight - albeit progressively deeper - into the noble truths.
Nevertheless, the evidence seems to indicate that in some cases, the Buddha's included, the progression - if there is any - is so rapid as to have never been clearly recorded. This is likely best interpreted as showing how the minds of some remarkable people come into the world almost entirely primed to drop all passion and delight for everything in the cosmos, and beyond.
